# Compute % sales made on weekend compared with total sales week pandas and how to deal exceptions like bank holiday

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with daily sales.

I want to create a KPI to understand how weekend sales influence weekly sales and how normal days influence  weekly sales.

I created a working code as an example below, It works.

But:

### 1) (first MAIN question) I think could be improved in a more Pythonic way but I don't know how

2) (second minor question)In case of bank holiday where sales are too low or special holiday where sales are too high should I substitute these outliers with mean or median values?

```
#Generating a Random Sample
np.random.seed(30)
values=np.random.randint(0,400,14)
day= pd.date_range(start='25/02/2020',periods=14)

#Creating an example DataFrame
df_input={'date':day,"values":values}
df_test=pd.DataFrame(df_input)

#From here starts what I have done on my original code
# week and day of the week are two informatio that I have to retrieve from my
#original DataFrame
#Creating a column with Week and Day Of The Week info
df_test['week']=df_test.date.dt.week
df_test['day']=df_test.date.dt.dayofweek

#Creating a Column for differencing weekend from normal day 
df_test['weekend']=np.zeros(len(df_test))
df_test['weekend'][(df_test.day==5)|(df_test.day==6)]=1

#Grouping on Week to get total sales 
grouped_full=df_test.groupby(['week']).sum()

#Grouping on Week And Weekend to separate normal days from weekend days
grouped=df_test.groupby(['week','weekend']).sum()

#Getting the ratio between 
#the weekend and total weekly sales
#normal days and total weekly sales
ratio=grouped/grouped_full
print(ratio['values'])
```

This is my output:

```
week  weekend
9     0.0        0.666667
      1.0        0.333333
10    0.0        0.784127
      1.0        0.215873
11    0.0        1.000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time trying to really understand how you're approaching the problem and if there's another way to look at it.

**I'm no professional by any means so take all of this with a grain of salt:**

1. I don't think there's a more "pythonic" way to make your code.  Although extensive, I can show you a way my brain approached your
   problem as I understood it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#Generating a Random Sample
np.random.seed(30)
values=np.random.randint(0,400,14)
day= pd.date_range(start='25/02/2020',periods=14)

#Creating an example DataFrame
df_input={'date':day,"values":values}
df_test=pd.DataFrame(df_input)

# group and use mean
weekdays = (df_test[df_test.date.dt.weekday.isin([0,1,2,3,4])]
                .groupby(df_test.date.dt.week)
                .mean())
# group and use mean
weekends = (df_test[df_test.date.dt.weekday.isin([5,6])]
                .groupby(df_test.date.dt.week)
                .mean())

# store in dict
d = {'weekdays': weekdays, 'weekends': weekends}

# concat and drop extra level('values')
both = pd.concat(d, axis=1).droplevel(1, axis=1)

# create new column with mean ratio differences
both['weekends_ratio'] = both['weekends'].div(both['weekends']+both['weekdays'])

print(both)
```

```
      weekdays  weekends  weekend_ratio
date
9          280     280.0       0.500000
10         247     170.0       0.407674
11          18       NaN            NaN
```

2. I don't know if it'll help but maybe use `.mean()`(as you see in my code) instead of
   `.sum()` to find the ratio difference in average sales.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I would have liked to comment on Ukranian-serge answer but eventually it is not possible due to the 50points reputation rule but I don't care and I want to contribute anyway.

I would point out that technically your answer is responding only to the latter part of the question:

> I want to create a KPI to understand how weekend sales influence weekly sales and how normal days influence weekly sales

indeed by grouping for the same week number we create the KPI with a causal relation of Weekdays --> Weekend while for doing the contrary we should use:

```py
# group and use mean
weekdays = (df_test[df_test.date.dt.weekday.isin([0,1,2,3,4])]
                .groupby(df_test.date.dt.week)
                .mean())
# group and use mean
weekends = (df_test[df_test.date.dt.weekday.isin([5,6])]
                .groupby(df_test.date.dt.week -1 )
                .mean())
```

in order to find the Weekend --> Weekday causal relation

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

A possible alternative

```
# Creating an example DataFrame
np.random.seed(30)
values = np.random.randint(0,400,14)
day = pd.date_range(start='25/02/2020',periods=14)
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'date':day,"values":values})

# Create week, day, weekend
df_test['week'] = df_test['date'].dt.week
df_test['day'] = df_test['date'].dt.dayofweek
df_test['weekend'] = df_test['day'].isin([5,6])# optional --> .astype(int)

# Calculate the metric
df_test_grouped = df_test.groupby(['week', 'weekend'])[['values']].sum()
df_test_grouped.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))
```

**Question 2**
It's really hard to say, it depends on the type of the analysis, the assumptions you're making, how much data you have, the scale of the outliers, etc.
Often outliers are important numbers, not just values to smooth out.
E.g. the Christmas week can provide 20% of the yearly sales of a certain product. Is that week just an outlier?